# How do you CD change directory into the absolute path of a symbolic linked directory?

Tags: bash

I'm currently in a symbolic link directory and I want to go up one level in the absolute path, but I cant as it will hit me back up to my home directory (~). I can do pwd -P to get the absolute path, but how do I pipe that result into the cd command? I always thought it was this: {}

Sample:

```
10:21:55 {master *} ~/ch$ pwd -P 
/home/drupal/sites/all/themes/house

10:22:16 {master *} ~/ch$ pwd -P | cd {}
bash: cd: {}: No such file or directory

10:22:20 {master *} ~/ch$
```

Comment: simplest command would be: " cd -P . "

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me:

```
cd `pwd -P`
```

You can also use `cd -P` like this:

```
cd -P ~/ch
```

or if you're already in the symlinked directory:

```
cd -P .
```

Answer (score 6):

You can insert the output of some command into the command line with the *command substitution operator* `$(...)`.

For example, this will go to the *physical current working directory* (all symbolic links resolved):

```
cd $(pwd -P)
```

To go up one level (your ultimate goal, as I understood):

```
cd $(pwd -P)/..
```